# eps-open-rtos: sdk_wifi_station_get_connect_status returns 255

Tags: esp8266, rtos

Even in included HTTP get demo sdk_wifi_station_get_connect_status() returns 255 even before try to connect. And of course it refuses to connect to 
There is no any documentation this status.

Is there any suggestion on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you need to config the esp on user_init() function and call function sdk_wifi_station_get_connect_status() inside a task

```
#include "espressif/esp_common.h"
#include "esp/uart.h"
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "ssid_config.h"
#include "esp8266.h"
void task1(void *pvParameters)
{
    while (1)
    {
        check_wifi_connection();
    }
}
void check_wifi_connection()
{
    uint8_t status = sdk_wifi_station_get_connect_status();
    while (status != STATION_GOT_IP)
    {
        status = sdk_wifi_station_get_connect_status();
        vTaskDelay(ONE_SEC / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        switch (status)
        {
        case STATION_WRONG_PASSWORD:
            printf("WiFi: wrong password\n\r");
            break;
        case STATION_NO_AP_FOUND:
            printf("WiFi: AP not found\n\r");
            break;
        case STATION_CONNECT_FAIL:
            printf("WiFi: connection failed\r\n");
            break;
        case STATION_GOT_IP:
            break;
        default:
            printf("%s: status = %d\n\r", __func__, status);
            break;
        }
    }
}
void user_init(void)
{
    uart_set_baud(0, BAUDRATE);
    sdk_wifi_set_opmode(STATION_MODE);
    sdk_wifi_station_set_auto_connect(true);
    sdk_wifi_station_set_config(&config);// my config that
    gpio_enable(gpio, GPIO_INPUT);
    tsqueue = xQueueCreate(2, sizeof(uint32_t));
    xTaskCreate(&task1,
                "task1",
                2048,
                NULL,
                tskIDLE_PRIORITY,
                &task_handler);
}
```